# Cake2 - show data from 2 identical databases

Tags: database, orm, cakephp-2.0

i have quite large application with complex DB structure (lots of tables with foregin keys.. ).

This application exists in 2 instances ( so there are 2 schema-identical DB's ), every has different data (some data can be same like 'district').

I need to create third application for reading data only. This third application needs to read data from both databases, merging them and displaying them.

I need to by able to use existing application code for reading, sorting, filtering, paginating.

What is most effective way to achieve this in cakephp?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution:
- create your own data source ( extend existing Mysql )
- overload "read" method, in this overloaded method, merge records and return